# How do you uninstall the 'sudo' command?

Tags: sudo, su

I had heard someone mention it once, is this an urban legend or can you actually do it? I'm trying googling to find where the sudo command is or what file defines it, but googling `remove sudo` or anything `sudo defined` it isn't very fruitful results.

Comment: Whatever the standard method for your distribution is

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Be careful about urban legends. There is also another good one about `rm -rf /*`
 speeding up your disks. Please think a little before posting nonsense.

Comment: CVE-2021-3156 and many more are good reasons to do this.... as I would expect somebody named @LinuxSecurityFreak to understand :-)

Answer (score 2):

While @aokellermann is technically correct (the best kind of correct!) in that a simple `apt-get purge sudo` would remove `sudo` ... and it could take a lot of other stuff with it.  Use `apt-cache rdepends sudo` and you'll see all packages that depend on it.  If you use Ubuntu, the `ubuntu-minimal` package depends on `sudo`.  Of course, `apt` will prompt you to make sure you wish to do anything....

Some distributions - like Debian - don't install it as part of a minimal install, or if they do, the system isn't configured to depend on them so heavily (ie, a root password is set during install and you are expected to log in on a console as root or use `su -` or similar to gain root access after using `ssh` to connect)

If you wish to prevent `sudo` from being used on a system that has it somewhat integrated (Ubuntu, Mint, etc) then configure it properly via `visudo` (I recomend `EDITOR=/bin/nano visudo` actually) and appropriate group membership for users.

Comment: The questioner has not even specified Linux, let alone a Linux operating system that uses APT.

Answer (score -2):

"Sudo" is the name of a package, which contains the command "sudo". Removing the package with your distro's package manager should work. If you use the APT package manager you could execute

```
$ apt-get purge sudo
```